# how to use clause where and group with 2 paramater in code igniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have model like this

## Model:

```
public function lihatgajiharian($id,$tglitung){
$status='m';
          $this->db->select('count( tgl ) AS total, absen.id, pegawai.nama, pegawai.bagian, pegawai.bagian, pegawai.tglmasuk, gaji.jenis_gaji, gaji.jumlah, gajiharian.id_gajiharian, gajiharian.status, gajiharian.tgldigaji,
          (CASE WHEN (weekday( tgl ) <=3) THEN date( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 - weekday( tgl ) )DAY )
          ELSE date( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 +7 - weekday( tgl ) )DAY )END) AS tglitung');
          $this->db->from('absen');
          $this->db->join('pegawai', 'pegawai.id = absen.id');
          $this->db->join('gaji', 'gaji.id = pegawai.id');
          $this->db->join('gajiharian', 'gajiharian.= absen.id','left');
          $this->db->where('absen.id',$id);
          $this->db->where('absen.status',$status);
          $this->db->group_by('absen.id');
          $this->db->group_by('tglitung');  
          $this->db->having('tglitung', $tglitung);
          $query = $this->db->get();
          return $query->row();
```

and appear error,

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'absen`.`id`WHERE`absen`.`id`= '15' AND`absen`.`status`= 'm' GROUP BY`abs' at line 6
>   but if I try run query in sql like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check near third join `gajiharian` you have put only dot there not with column add it and problem will be solved...

```
$status='m';
          $this->db->select('count( tgl ) AS total, absen.id, pegawai.nama, pegawai.bagian, pegawai.bagian, pegawai.tglmasuk, gaji.jenis_gaji, gaji.jumlah, gajiharian.id_gajiharian, gajiharian.status, gajiharian.tgldigaji,
          (CASE WHEN (weekday( tgl ) <=3) THEN date( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 - weekday( tgl ) )DAY )
          ELSE date( tgl + INTERVAL( 3 +7 - weekday( tgl ) )DAY )END) AS tglitung');
          $this->db->from('absen');
          $this->db->join('pegawai', 'pegawai.id = absen.id');
          $this->db->join('gaji', 'gaji.id = pegawai.id');
          $this->db->join('gajiharian', 'gajiharian.column= absen.id','left'); //in this line problem occurs
          $this->db->where('absen.id',$id);
          $this->db->where('absen.status',$status);
          $this->db->group_by('absen.id');
          $this->db->group_by('tglitung');  
          $this->db->having('tglitung', $tglitung);
          $query = $this->db->get();
          return $query->row();
```